# Will an implicit cursor ever fail to close in PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql, database-cursor

With PL/SQL will there ever be a situation, say in the case of an exception, where an implicit cursor will fail to close?

I understand that an implicit cursor is supposed to close itself after use, but just want to know if there's ever a situation where this might not be the case, and if this is possible, what kind of remediation will be a good idea.

Comment: It may help if you define exactly what you mean by "implicit cursor".  Do you mean a FOR loop using SQL, or DML?

Answer (score 2):

When `COMMIT or ROLLBACK` fails the cursor will **not** close automatically
It is recommended to use route bellow when using cursors:

```
-- before using the cursor
    IF your_cursor %ISOPEN THEN
         CLOSE your_cursor;
    END IF;
   OPEN your_cursor;

-- after using the cursor
         CLOSE your_cursor;
-- when exception
    IF your_cursor %ISOPEN THEN
         CLOSE your_cursor;
    END IF;
```

Comment: So in this situation if either COMMIT or ROLLBACK fails, will an exception be thrown? If so, would it not be better to so something like:

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  IF MyCursor %IS_OPEN THEN
    CLOSE MyCursor;
  END IF;

Comment: But that is using an *explicit* cursor. The OP is talking about *implicit* cursors (`for foo_rec in (select * from foo) loop ...`). In that case there is no cursor variable and no way to test it with `%isopen`.

Comment: There is actually @a_horse_with_no_name, you can use SQL%ISOPEN (see my answer) it just _always_ returns false.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you're talking about implicit cursors, i.e. a SELECT INTO... or a DML statement executed within a PL/SQL block as opposed to a FOR loop.

As with explicit cursors implicit cursors have attributes; you can use `SQL%NOTFOUND` (instead of `CURSOR_NAME%NOTFOUND` for instance.

To quote from the [11.1 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/sql_cursor.htm) on implicit cursor attributes for `SQL%ISOPEN`:

> Always returns FALSE, because the database closes the SQL cursor
>   automatically after executing its associated SQL statement.

This should, I believe, be taken to mean that the cursors will be closed after execution, whether an exception is raised or not. After all, an execution halted due to an exception is still a executed SQL statement.

The reason has been removed from [the 11.2 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10472/sql_cursor.htm).

> SQL%ISOPEN always has the value FALSE.

It appears to have been added to the [chapter on implicit cursors](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#i46192) instead:

> SQL%ISOPEN always returns FALSE, because an implicit cursor always
>   closes after its associated statement runs.

Whether the cursor closes or not doesn't really matter due to the answer to your final question, *"what kind of remediation will be a good idea."*. To quote from the same chapter:

> You cannot control an implicit cursor, but you can get information
>   from its attributes.

So, no. There's no remediation possible; it is impossible to explicitly close an implicitly opened cursor.

The one thing you might want to test is whether you can raise [ORA-0100: Maximum open cursors exceeded](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-01000) using solely implicit cursors as this is the worst consequence I can think of.

Comment: According to the manual you can **not** reference `SQL%ISOPEN` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#CJABCJEA : "*However, because select_statement is not an independent statement, the implicit cursor is internal - you cannot reference it with the name SQL*"

Answer (score 1):

Let's define an "implicit cursor" as a SELECT statement executed in a FOR loop.

Looking at it from a practical point of view - regardless of whether or not it's possible for an implicit cursor to be left open, the important question is "What can you do about it?".  To the best of my knowledge, the answer to that question is "Nothing".  You don't have a cursor variable to work with, there's no way (that I know of) to access the implicit cursor, and thus  you really can't affect it.

There's two things you can do.  The first is to completely avoid the use of implicit cursors.  Only use explicit cursors, go through all the steps of opening, fetching, closing, etc.  This gives you the maximum level of control.  If you're into this sort of thing, go for it.

On the other hand, you can use implicit cursors and just not worry.  I'm good with not worrying.  :-)  Seriously, though, implicit cursors are IMO hugely better than explicit cursors.  There's less code to write, and therefore less code to screw up.  The system can, in certain circumstances, optimize the use of implicit cursors without requiring you to write a pile of extra code.  The code you write is cleaner and more easily understood - not a concern if you're working in a one man shop where *you* write and maintain all the code, but out here in Corporateville we often have to write code others will maintain and vice versa, and it's considered polite to hand over the cleanest, clearest code we possibly can.  There are times (such as when handing a cursor variable back to a caller from outside of Oracle) when explicit cursors are necessary, but for most code I'm using implicit FOR-LOOP cursors - **and *LOVING* it**!  (And extra bonus points for those who can recall where ***that*** comes from :-)

Share and enjoy.